# Auto height and the float issue

Tags: html, css

I have had this issue before and can't remember if and how I fixed it.

I have to create a scenario where I have 2 DIV's floated left and right inside a parent DIV. The 2 floating DIV's have height:auto, but the parent ignores them (perfectly logical) and the background of the parent DIV can't be seen. I know what the issue is, but are there any suggestions of how to solve it? Or any alternatives, I am willing to try a new approach.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `clear:float` in a div inside parent div:

```
.clear
{
  clear:both;
}

<div id="parent">
 <div id="left"></div>
 <div id="right"></div>

 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**[There are more options available to solve this problem.](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Clearing_Space)**

Answer (score 0):

With no meaningless HTML element to be added, you can [clear floats the overflow way](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #allmychildrenfloat {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #allmychildrenfloat p {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<div id="allmychildrenfloat">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec leo arcu, iaculis at, ultricies et, porta eget, urna. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Or you could use `display: inline-block;` instead of the float property, it depends on your exact needs. IE7- doesn't understand this value but it's OK if you give IE6 and 7 `display: inline; zoom: 1;`. And if you still support Fx 2, there is also an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I know , it's tooo late to answer this question but anyone who is coming here after me can benefit from this answer.

USE 
 `display: inline-flex` 
instead of floats and be happy.

Note : you'll need to check for the support of inline-flex value